# reset downcounter in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run the downcounter in a loop that is after 5seconds the counter starts counting again from 5 to 0. 
I have tried this code

```
countDownTimer.cancel();
countDownTimer.start();
```

bt this does not work. The value in textview does not reset. Posted below is the complete code.
Regards!

```
private void timee() {

    for (int j = 5; j > 0; j--) {
        countDownTimer = new MalibuCountDownTimer(5000, 1000);
        if (j == 4)
            countDownTimer.start();
        else {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            countDownTimer.start();
        }
    }
}

// CountDownTimer class
public class MalibuCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public MalibuCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // takeImage();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        tt.setText("Time remain:" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: what you want in reset set it o and start again?

Comment: set it to 5 and start again down counting to 0. Like it worked the first time. That's what I want to achieve for each decrements in the loop i.e reset to 5 and down count to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your timee() method and CountDownTimer class with following code

```
private void timee(){

        MalibuCountDownTimer countDownTimer=new MalibuCountDownTimer(5000, 1000);
            countDownTimer.start();

}
public class MalibuCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public MalibuCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        j++;
        if(j<=5)
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        m_tv_emp.setText("Time remain:" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }
}
```

note: take j as class varieble

Comment: Thank you so much it worked perfectly. I don't have enough  reputation to give a vote to this answer. Thank you for quick solution.

Comment: You can't up vote my answer but can you please accept my answer?